# Laravel - Route not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that is using the Laravel forms package, the head of this form looks like this:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->username), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

This form is inside the edit blade at `views/users/edit.blade.php`

To my knowledge `'route' => array('users.update', $user->$username)` does the following:
finds a route with the name `users.update` and adds in the user's username as a parameter.

Inside `routes/web.php` I have this:

```
Route::post('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
```

Given this I'm assuming the following:

The form goes to the named route and converts it into `www.example.com/users/username`

However, when I go to the edit page, which has the updating form inside of it, I get:

`"Route [users.update] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\my-newable\resources\views\users\edit.blade.php)"`

Even stranger is that when I run `php artisan route:list` the route in question is not even listed as a route that you can use within the application.

I have also tried the following command: `php artisan route:cache`

But it still doesn't appear?

Finally, this is the update method with the `UsersController`

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{  
    $user = User::findOrFail($user)->first(); 

    //Validate name, email and password fields  
    $this->validate($request, [

    ]);

    $roles = $request['roles']; //Retreive all roles

    if (isset($roles)) 
    {        
        $user->roles()->sync($roles);  //If one or more role is selected associate user to roles          
    }        
    else 
    {
        $user->roles()->detach(); //If no role is selected remove exisiting role associated to a user
    }

    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('flash_message', 'User successfully edited.');
}
```

I'm just not seeing how the `users.update` method is not defined?

Comment: I'm using `$username` as the Primary Key in the User model.

Comment: As a side note, using strings/varchars as Primary Key in a database is generally a bad idea. You should use an integer. Using strings as Primary Key will slow down your database significantly.

Comment: It was more because I wanted to be able to search users by username, and so that the URL slugs contained more human readable elements. If there is a way of having friendly URLs and still using the ID I'd be interested in hearing about that.

Comment: Yes there is! You should watch this video: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/31 While you're at it, just watch the entire series. It's good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Try `php artisan route:clear`.
According to the documentation `php artisan route:cache` generates the cached routes file and each time you add a new one this needs to be refreshed. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#route-caching

I don't know if route:cache also resets the cached routes. I hope route:clear helps :)

Comment: route:cache does reset your cache.